# What are the UIButton patterns around color?

Tags: iphone, xcode, design-patterns

I know Green is action/submit, Red is destructive/delete but how about the Gray and Yellow buttons?

Comment: Not quite a SO question. As no colors have a hard standard meaning. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Dude u downrated me because I asked a question around patterns? Seriously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please feel free to edit this post and add additional findings.
I took a look at the System Apps, and this is what i found:

## Red

As you noted, red buttons are used to indicate destructive consequences. This is used very consistently, examples include:

- Deleting a contact in the Phone App
- Deleting Photos in the Photos App
- Deleting notes in the Notes App

## Blue

In the system Apps, blue is used to signal that a button takes the user out of editing mode, without reverting or introducing new changes. These buttons are mostly named "Done" with the exception of lists where the user selects multiple items to apply actions on via using other buttons. In this case their title is "Cancel".
Examples:

- When selecting Mails to delete/move/mark in the Mail App, the button named "Cancel" is blue.
- When selecting multiple photos to share/delete/... in the Photos app, the "Cancel"-button is blue as well.
- When editing a contact in the Phone App, the "Done" button is blue.

Exceptions:

- In the Reminders App, white buttons play the same role.
- The button to publish a video to YouTube in the Photos App is blue
- Blue is also used to return to the Camera when browsing Photos via the Camera App and to return to recording when browsing previous recordings in the Voice Memo App.
- Blue is used to indicate the state of a button that toggles between speakers and earpiece in the Voice Memos App

Note that when editing a single Photo in the Photos App, the "Cancel" button is black, because it undoes the changes made to the Photo.

## Green

Green buttons are, as you said, used to submit/buy/start something. Examples:

- The buttons to buy items in the AppStore and iTunes Apps are green.
- In the Clock App, green buttons start a timer or stopwatch.
- Sending an SMS (not an iMessage) in the Messages App is done via a green button.

Exception: Again, the button to publish a video to YouTube in the Photos App is blue, while, imho, it should be green.

## Yellow

The only cases of yellow being used for buttons i know of are the buttons that save the made changes when editing a movie or photo in the Photos app.

## Grey

As with yellow, i know only two examples of grey buttons. The buttons in the Clock app for pausing/resuming a timer and for marking laps/reseting the stopwatch.